# Vncsharpwpf error

Tags: wpf, vnc

I downloaded a code [a link](http://www.mediafire.com/file/o71m1ntfdf1rdkq/VncSharpWpf-0.0.2.zip) after i run it from VS2010 the error show up

1. Warning    3   The tag 'RemoteDesktopWpf' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:VncSharpWpf;assembly=VncSharpWpf'. Line 44 Position 14.   C:\VNCSHARPWPF\VncSharpWpf-0.0.2_2\VncSharpWpf_Example\MainWindow.xaml  44  14  VncSharpWpf_Example
2. Warning 2   Importing key file "VncSharpWpf.pfx" was canceled.  VncSharpWpf
3. Warning 1   Cannot import the following key file: VncSharpWpf.pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_1F91AEA45AB30623   VncSharpWpf

Answer (score 0):

Delete `VncSharpWpf.pfx` from project `VncSharpWpf`, and you can build the project.